# Grouping of women in the beginning of Parashat Nitzavim

Tags: women, commentaries, parashat-nitzavim

Parashat Nitzavim starts with the following Psukim ([Devarim 29,9](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Deuteronomy.29.9?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)), grouping the Jewish Nation into two parts:

> "אַתֶּם נִצָּבִים הַיּוֹם כֻּלְּכֶם לִפְנֵי ה"א רָאשֵׁיכֶם שִׁבְטֵיכֶם זִקְנֵיכֶם וְשֹׁטְרֵיכֶם כֹּל אִישׁ יִשְׂרָאֵל׃"
>
> You stand this day, all of you, before the LORD your God—your tribal heads, your elders and your officials, all the men of Israel,
>
> "טַפְּכֶם נְשֵׁיכֶם וְגֵרְךָ אֲשֶׁר בְּקֶרֶב מַחֲנֶיךָ מֵחֹטֵב עֵצֶיךָ עַד שֹׁאֵב מֵימֶיךָ׃"
>
> "your children, your wives, even the stranger within your camp, from woodchopper to water drawer"

1. Why are the women listed in the second group with the children and the strangers?
2. Why are the women listed after the children and next to the strangers?